# How to add url link to ImageButton in android

Tags: android, webview, imagebutton

I have an android web-view app in which i have added some ImageButtons, and now i want to add url links to that ImageButton, link should open with app in webview. following are my codes

image_button.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView">

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/_button"
        android:clickable="true"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
       />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

ImageButton.java

public class ImageButton extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
NavigationView navigation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_button);
    initInstances();
}
public void image_button1 (View view) {
    goToUrl ( "http://google.com/");
}

public void image_button2 (View view) {
    goToUrl ( "http://google.com/");
}

private void goToUrl (String url) {
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent WebView = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(WebView;
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find an appropriate solution to this? I'm looking to do the same within my app.

Answer (score 0):

You must call image_button1() and image_button2() methods in your xml like android:onClick = "image_buton1" and android:onClick = "image_button2"

Comment: thanks for correction,  have added that now. but link still opens in browser instead of in app webview.

Comment: You must define webview in your xml for example you can look up this link https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/webview/android-webview-example/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Uri.parse or to use intents. You can simply call loadUrl on the Webview. The loadUrl method handles everything in the background for you, so its okay if its called on the main UI thread

Unless you are using the the layout inflator, you need to create a web view in your xml

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In Java

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
```

And then in the onClickListener of the ImageButton, just call webview.loadUrl(someUrl)

```
ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button);

imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
            }
        });
```

Lastly, make sure that you have the permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your web view own client, the **client open the url in the app**.

//Your FirstActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_button);
    initInstances();
}
public void image_button1 (View view) {
    goToUrl ( "http://google.com/");
}

public void image_button2 (View view) {
    goToUrl ( "http://google.com/");
}

private void goToUrl (String url) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Url",url);
    startActivity(WebView;
}
```

//Your WebView Activity 
 WebView webview;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);

    //get url from intent 
    String url= getIntent().getStringExtra("Url");
    webview = (WebView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.webView);

     yelpWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        else {
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClientTwo());
        webview.loadUrl(url); 
} 

public class myWebClientTwo extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           // progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //progressBar.setProgress(0);
            SVProgressHUD.showInView(getActivity(), "Loading", true);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            SVProgressHUD.showInView(getActivity(), "Loading", true);
           // progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            //progressBar.setProgress(100);
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss(getActivity());
        }
    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && yelpWeb.canGoBack()) {
            yelpWeb.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return getActivity().onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Add Permision in Manifest File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

[@Sagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6498956/sagar-chaudhary)

Comment: Will this work from a `Fragment`? I have an `imageButton` nested in a `Fragment`, which I'd like to open a web page within the application.

Comment: Yes @AndroidDevBro

Comment: Thanks. Also, what did you mean by the "WebView Activity Webview webview? Is it just a Java class, or...?

Comment: It's your **Activity** or **Fragment**